# Generating Pyramid to Show Numbers in Module 10

Tags: java

I am trying to generate pyramid starts with the number one (1), in each row the first digit determines the number of row. In addition, the first number in the row also determines the number of numbers in that order (according to module 10). All other numbers in a row we calculate by adding the number from the left and the number above it, according to module 10.

```
int n = 12;
int i, j;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      int module = i % 10;

      System.out.print(module + " ");

    }

    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

With my implementation, I get

```
1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

The actual result should be

```
1
2 3
3 5 8
4 7 2 0
5 9 6 8 8
6 1 0 6 4 2
7 3 4 4 0 4 6
8 5 8 2 6 6 0 6
9 7 2 0 2 8 4 4 0
0 9 6 8 8 0 8 2 6 6
1 1 0 6 4 2 2 0 2 8 4
2 3 4 4 0 4 6 8 8 0 8 2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you "add the number above it". How do you plan to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can just print it if you want to add the previous number.

Comment: @Progman I don't know how I can do that because I need to get the left and left above numbers of the current number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you write a helper method to calculate the digit to display. This method takes as an argument the row index and column index or the row number and column number, whatever you are more comfortable with. Assuming we use 0-based indices for the row and column, we can define the following values for that method:

- When the column index is 0 (so we are in the first column), the return value is the row index + 1 modulo 10.
- When the row index is 0 (so we are at the top), the return value is 1.
- For all the other positions, we use a recursive call of the helper method to add "the number from the left" with "the number above it".

The helper method will look like this:

```
/**
 * Calculate the digits. The arguments are 0 based.
 * 
 * @param row The row index
 * @param column The column index
 * @return The digit to display
 */
public static int calculateDigit(int row, int column) {
    if (row < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The row index must not be negative");
    }
    if (column < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The column index must not be negative");
    }
    if (column == 0) {
        return (row+1) % 10; // simply return the row number
    }
    if (row == 0) {
        return 1; // in the first row, so it is the "1"
    }
    // calculate the new number based on the expression
    // "adding the number from the left and the number above it"
    int left = calculateDigit(row, column-1);
    int above = calculateDigit(row-1, column-1);
    int sum = left + above;
    int modulo = sum % 10;
    return modulo;
}
```

You can use this helper method in the simple two `for` loops you already have.

```
for (int r=0; r<10; r++) {
    for (int c=0; c<=r; c++) {
        int value = calculateDigit(r, c);
        System.out.print(value+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

And this will get you the expected output:

```
1 
2 3 
3 5 8 
4 7 2 0 
5 9 6 8 8 
6 1 0 6 4 2 
7 3 4 4 0 4 6 
8 5 8 2 6 6 0 6 
9 7 2 0 2 8 4 4 0 
0 9 6 8 8 0 8 2 6 6
```

Comment: Thank you! Comments are helpful to understand. Can you please tell me how you achieved this implementation?

Comment: @DianaJ This helper method and the `for` loops (which are similar to the one you already have) are ready to use. You don't need to do anything further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your results to use it print next line.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 12;
    int i,j;
    int[][] arr = new int[n][n];

    arr[0][0] = 1;
    System.out.println(arr[0][0]);

    for(i = 1;i<n;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<=i;j++) {
        if(j == 0) {
          arr[i][j] = (i+1)%10;
        }else {
          arr[i][j] = (arr[i][j-1] + arr[i-1][j-1])%10;
        }
        System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `arr[i][j] = i+1;` should be `arr[i][j] = (i+1) % 10;`